# Deleting Old (Non-Boot) Windows Vista Directory From Command-Line

Tags: windows, windows-vista, scripting

Does anyone have a good script that will delete an old, non-booting, inactive Windows directory from the command-line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umm...

```
rd /s /q <directory name>
```

From a CMD command prompt.

How's that work for you?

Edit:

Okay-- how about:

```
takeown /F <directory name> /R /D Y
cacls <directory name> /T /G Everyone:F
rd /s /q <directory name>
```

Should be run from an elevated command-prompt.

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't address the various permissions and results in access denied on many files.  I was playing around with something with taking ownership, then changing the permissions, and then deleting, but it doesn't seem to always work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what OS you are running, but if it is Vista, instructions on deleting the windows.old directory can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930527 or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933212 (they pretty much say the same thing).

Edit: I see in the subject line that it is Vista... Those KB articles should do the trick.